# Control Order of Attribute Fields in Azure AD B2C Policies

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is it possible to control the order in which the attribute fields are displayed when Azure AD B2C generates the html for a signup page? I am familiar with how to style the resulting fields, based on their unique ids if necessary. But I don't see a way of controlling the order in which they're displayed (e.g., so the surname/last name field doesn't appear first).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the field order by:

1. Editing the built-in policy
2. Selecting **Page UI customization**
3. Selecting **Local account sign-up page**
4. Moving the **Sign-up attributes** list items up and down using the drag icon to left of the attribute name.

Comment: Thanx, @ChrisPadgett! I don't recall seeing that in the documentation I've read, and would not have thought to check for it myself.